# Accesss control for Peer Administrators in hyperledger fabric composer applications

Tags: admin, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer, access-control

My questions are about access control for Peer Administrators versus access control for "Network Admins" in a hyperledger fabric composer application.

1.) 
As far as I understand, the Peer Administrators are the only ones who can deploy a new business network or upgrade a running business network, correct?

2.)
The "Network Admins" are normal participants, whose access rights can be determined in the ACL file. That is, I could, e.g., limit the rights of Network Admins to the task of creating new participants, correct?

3.)
What access rights does a peer administrator have by default? (E.g., is he/she able to view old transactions?) ... And how do I manipulate the access rights of a peer administrator?

4.) How do I prevent a Peer Administrator from looking at all the data saved in the ledger? (Or is there nothing I have to do because this is impossible for the peer administrator anyway?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using the Development Fabric created by following the Composer Documentation:

1)  Yes - PeerAdmin is the only ID that can install/start/upgrade networks.

2)  The Network Admin is a Participant that is bound to ID, and it can be denied/allowed access through an ACL (like other participants).  Note that the Network Admin participant type comes from the system namespace `org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin`, and participants you create will normally come from the namespace you define in your model.

3)  PeerAdmin has no access to the Business Network.  It is an ID recognised by the CA, but is not bound to a participant in the Business Network and has no access.

4)  Correct - do nothing - there is no access.